# show that $ \lim_{\substack{ x\to +\infty \\ y\to 2 } }\left(1+\dfrac{y}{x} \right)^{x}=e^{2} $

Tags: limits, contest-math

Show that $\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{ x\to +\infty \\ y\to 2 } }\left(1+\dfrac{y}{x} \right)^{x}=e^2 $

in other terms Let $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\left(1+\dfrac{y}{x} \right)^{x}$

calculate the limit $f(x,y)$ when $(x,y)\to (+\infty,2) $

the source is from french math  contest as MCQ Question
[image]

Comment: Since the source of the problem seems to be a multiple choice Question, the recent edit does not add much to help Readers know what requires an explanation or a calculation.  That is, the form of the problem dictates that the limit exists and should be one of the three given values.   It would be best to state if you want a justification of that or simply to be told which of the three is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $2>\epsilon>0$ and take $2-\epsilon <y < 2+\epsilon$ and take $x>M$ for some large positive $M$.

Note that the function

$$
f(x,y)=(1+y/x)^x
$$
is strictly increasing in $y$ for $x,y>0$. Thus, 
$$
(1+\frac{2-\epsilon}{x})^x<(1+y/x)^x<(1+\frac{2+\epsilon}{x})^x
$$
but for very large $M$ and $x>M$, 
$$
(1+\frac{2-\epsilon}{x})^x\sim e^{2-\epsilon}\\
(1+\frac{2+\epsilon}{x})^x\sim e^{2+\epsilon}
$$

so for these large $x$ we have 
$$
e^{2-\epsilon}<(1+y/x)^x<(1+\frac{2-\epsilon}{x})^x<e^{2+\epsilon}
$$
since choice of epsilon was arbitrary, we have the desired limit.

Comment: Why would the iterated limit be equal to the limit in two variables? The fact that the two are equal is immaterial. Consider $\lim_{(x,y)\to \infty} \delta_{x,y}$.

Comment: No, this is not true. Yes, I downvoted all the answers.

Comment: It means that whenever the point $(x,y)$ is close to $(\infty,2)$ (i.e. $x$ is sufficiently large and simultaneously $y$ is sufficiently close to $2$), the value of $(1+\frac{y}{x})^x$ is close to $e^2$.

Comment: Yes, I have already given one in the first comment. It's not about interchanging limits, it's about iterating them in the first place.

Comment: @tomasz let me know if with the edits it is ok. I tried to avoid making a continuity argument since we have a limit at infinity

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a continuity argument as long as you can show that you can extend to continuous function defined at $(\infty,2)$ (i.e. that the limit exists). There are a few problems: in your the first inequality, it should probably be $2+\epsilon$ in the numerator on the right hand side. In what follows, to make it precise, you need to know that the expression converges to exponential uniformly (which it does, in bounded intervals). Detailed computation would involve another $\epsilon$ or two, but I think you've captured the gist, which is enough for this sort of question.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $y$ and consider the change of variables $u = x/y$. Then, $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^x = \lim_{u\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)^{uy}$$ Recall that $e = \lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/n)^n$. Thus, the limit is equivalent to $e^y$. Letting $y\to 2$ yields the result.

Comment: Why can you iterate limits?

Comment: You can iterate limits when the limit exists. It is a bit more of a technical discussion to say why the limit exists. What is your mathematical background?

Comment: I'm a third year PhD student. My point is, the main difficulty in this problem is showing that the limit exists, which none of the answers even noted.

Comment: Should I add a reference to the Moore-Osgood theorem then?

Comment: It's hard to say how much you should say (which is why this question was closed), but this is most certainly not enough. I don't remember any Moore-Osgood theorem, but if I had to answer this question, I would probably look for an explicit estimate.

Comment: Moore-Osgood theorem states precisely when you can iterate the limits. I wanted to avoid the estimate type argument due to the lack of context for the question. In the future, should I be more technical, or just avoid questions that could obviously use more effort in them.

Comment: You've got a point. Going into technical details in a do-my-homework question is not a good idea. Nonetheless, not mentioning that there is something to show is dishonest, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here is my approach. I posted an image of it.]
Here is my approach. I just took the common limit for $e$ and then took the limit of $y$.